# If M and N are Neighbourhoods of point p, prove that M union N is also Nbd. of p

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology

I was going through the topic Neighbourhoods (Nbds) as part of Real Analysis and there i happen to ponder over some properties of Nbds, properties pertaining to intersections was discussed but no discussion of properties related to unions. i.e. if M and N are Nbds of p then M union N is Nbd of p.

I just need help to find out if such a property even exists and if it does then what is it's proof?
I couldn't find this property in any of the books i have.

Comment: Any set that is bigger than a neighbourhood of $p$ is still a neighbourhood of $p$. So unions are trivial.

Answer (score 1):

Neighborhood of p means open set containing p. An arbitrary union of open sets in $\mathbb{R}$ is open in $\mathbb{R}$ (the same holds for $\mathbb{R}^n$ and any topological space). To see this in the case of $\mathbb{R}^n$, $\mathbb{R}^n$ is a metric space also, so the typical definition for open set in $\mathbb{R}^n$ is that $U\subseteq \mathbb{R}$ is open if for any $x\in U$ there is a ball of some positive radius $\epsilon$ of x contained in U, that is:

$B_{\epsilon}(x) := \{y\in \mathbb{R}^n \mid\text{ } \mid \mid y - x\mid \mid < \epsilon\}\subseteq U$.

If you have a union of two open sets $U$ and $V$ and $a\in U\cup V$, then $a\in U$, so $\exists \epsilon > 0$ s.t. $B_{\epsilon}(a)\subseteq U\subseteq U\cup V$. Hence $U\cup V$ is open and contains $a$, so $U\cup V$ is a neighborhood of $a$.